# Combining multiple image files into a video while using filter_complex to apply a watermark

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to combine two ffmpeg operations into a single one.

Currently I have two sets of ffmpeg commands that first generate a video from existing images, then runs that video through ffmpeg again to apply a watermark.

I'd like to see if its possible to combine these into a single operation.

```
# Create the source video
ffmpeg -y \
-framerate 1/1 \
-i layer-%d.png \
-r 30 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
output.mp4

# Apply the watermark and render the final output
ffmpeg -y \
-i output.mp4 \
-i logo.png \
-filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=40:40[a][b];[b][a]overlay=(80):(main_h-200-80)" \
final.mp4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -y \
-framerate 1/1 -i layer-%d.png \
-i logo.png \
-filter_complex "[0:v]fps=30[img];
                 [1:v][img]scale2ref=40:40[a][b];[b][a]overlay=(80):(main_h-200-80)" \
final.mp4
```

(The use of scale2ref doesn't make sense since you're scaling to a fixed size).

Comment: Thanks again @Mulvya. You're a huge help with ffmpeg.